# Error when deploying the `authority` gem with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, authority-gem

I'm deploying a rails4 app from a dev machine to a server. This deployment has been working smoothly.

I have added authorisation to my application using the [authority gem](https://github.com/nathanl/authority). When I run ./bin/cap deploy I now get the error in the unicorn log that is listed below.

All of the files created with `rails g authority:install` on the dev machine have been committed to git and are being deployed to the server using `./bin/cap deploy`.

Any help appreciated.

```
I, [2013-10-08T14:06:42.579240 #2021]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-10-08T14:06:42.583257 #3594]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=3594
I, [2013-10-08T14:06:42.583904 #3594]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2013-10-08T14:06:42.743225 #3588] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Authority (NameError)
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/releases/20131008015646/config/initializers/authority.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/releases/20131008015646/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:595:in `init_worker_process'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:615:in `worker_loop'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/home/deployer/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
E, [2013-10-08T14:06:42.758457 #2021] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 3588 exit 1> worker=1
```

Comment: did you bundle install as part of the deploy?

Comment: Yes. A bundle install is performed and the gem (authority-2.7.0) appears in the /home/deployerapps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems directory.

Comment: run it with `bundle exec rails g authority:install` or check your virtual ruby installation if you have one

Comment: in any case, why are you running this on a production machine? that command is supposed to be executed on development environments anyways?

Comment: The cap deploy command is being run on the dev machine. The output above is from the production machine.

Comment: You should probably delete or answer this question, based on our conversation here: https://github.com/nathanl/authority/issues/61. Since it was a "computer gnomes" kind of thing, it's probably too localized to help others and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I wiped my production environment, changed nothing in my dev environment, and re-ran the cap deploy and it worked. Not sure what the reason for this was, but there is no reason to keep this open.